# NSNotification handling in multiple UIViewContoller in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiviewcontroller, nsnotificationcenter

I have few `UIViewController's` subclass. Each and every class has network calls, all these network calls are handled in separate class, whenever I get failure as response instead of delivery failure response to each class I want to show an alert by posting notification from my network class. All my alerts are displayed view an extension to `UIViewController`. 
Is there a way to add observer for the notification in my extension, so that I can post notification from my network class and the alert is show using this `UIViewController's` extension instead of adding/removing observer in each of my `UIViewController`.

Comment: just dont post the notification when a failure happens and show the alert from your network class?

Comment: I just don't want to get the Alert in my Model/Network classes.

Answer (score 0):

1. If your intention is to just show an error alert then I would recommend adding AppDelegate as notification listener and then present an alert on notification fire.
2. I, personally, would recommend completion blocks for networking
   making code scalable and debugging easy.
3. There is another alternative of creating a UIViewController subclass
   (say CustomVC) and registering it for the notification with an empty
   handler. And then create all your view controllers subclass of
   CustomVC. Each of your view controllers would however have to
   implement the handler and execute code based on the specific VC.

Comment: I have my classes which are inherited from UITableViewController as well as UIViewController. I need to subclass many of my classes, which needs code change I don't prefer doing this at the final stage. Can I do anything with the help of my existing UIViewController's extension?

Comment: I have listed all the options to my knowledge. If you have different types of VCs then I would advise #1 & #2 of my above suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to show alert, you can do it by displaying it from your network class instead of notification.

If you have some specific functionality to implement for every 
UIViewController in case of failure then create a parent controller (subclass of UIViewController) and  inherit all of your UIViewController from parent class  and implement all the notification work in parent controller even if you want any funcionality specific to a controller, you can override the parent class method.